# How do i make the correct method to display only the opinions from the users i follow and my own

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

You can see that i have 3 tables, one for users, other for opinions and the last one for people who you follow, and the people who follow you:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You already have the correct implementation. Your method just needs a small change:

```
def follow_and_own_opinions
  Opinion.where(author_id: followings + [self])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t have much information, but as I can see, if you are using ActiveRecord you can try doing a scope (custom queries that you define inside your Rails models with the scope method) with an association

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class Opinion < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   scope :followed, -> { where user_id: followings + [self] }
end
```

This allow you to call in opinions controller just the opinions of the people that you follow

```
#app/controllers/opinions_controller.rb
Class OpinionsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @opinions = Opinion.followed
   end
end
```

Other alternative if you don´t want to do a scope  is to try this in the opinions_controller

```
#app/controllers/opinions_controller.rb
Class OpinionsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @opinions = current_user&.followers&.find_by(opinion: @opinion)
   end
end
```